# Java Stream of Integer array to return List of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

I have the following code, which I believe could be improved by making it less imperative.

Is there a way to re-write this toward that end by using the Java Streams API?

It iterates through a list of Integers, filtering against a map of items, returning matches on id. The tricky part to me is it iterates through the *Integers*, but returns a list of *Items*.

```
private  Map<Integer,Thing> thingMap = new HashMap<Integer,Thing>();
// populate thingMap
//...

public List<Item> getItems(Integer[] item_ids) {
    if(item_ids == null || item_ids.length ==0){
        return null;
    }
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    for(Integer item_id : item_ids){
        Item d = itemMap.get(item_id);
        if( d !=null){
            items.add(d);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

Comment: Downvotes do not mean someone is offended, it means they think that your question _"does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"_ (source: the tooltip on the downvote button). I guess someone downvoted because you're not actually asking a question, so it is _unclear_.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that "tongue-in-cheek". I added my exact question, which I had thought was implicit, in case anyone wants to vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `filter` and `map` (which will infer the type).

```java
return Arrays.stream(item_ids)
    .filter(itemMap::containsKey)
    .map(itemMap::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Also can use,

```
List<String> collect = Arrays.stream(item_ids)
                                     .map(itemMap::get)
                                     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```